# If $x^2+x+1 = 0$ then find the value of $x^{1999}+x^{2000}$?

Tags: polynomials

> If $x^2+x+1 = 0$ then find the value of $x^{1999}+x^{2000}$.

I first tried finding the solution of the given equation and then substituting it in the expression whose value we have to find but I wasn't able to simplify it.

In a different approach I moved the terms around a bit and arrived at $x^3 = 1$.
But wouldn't that mean that $x = 1$ (which is clearly not possible since it wouldn't satisfy the given equation)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^3=1$ has one real root and two complex roots.  $x $ is not the real root so it must be one of the complex roots.  Don't worry about it.  You don't need to solve for x.  Note x^3=1 so x^1998=(x^3)^666=1.  So you have x^1999+x^2000=x+x^2=x^2+x+1-1=0-1=-1.

Comment: @fleablood I still don't understand. Why do we have $x^3=1$? It doesn't satisfy $x^2+x+1=0$...

Comment: Yes it does.  If $x = -\frac 12 \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  Then both $x^3 = 1$.  And $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$.  Remember $x^3 = 1$ has ***THREE*** solutions.  $x = 1$ is only *one* of them and it is the one that doesn't work.  But the other two do.  This is what is called a *primative* root of unity. And $x^n = 1$ will have $n$ solutions and *some* of them will satisisfy $x^{n-1} + ....  + x + 1 = 0$ but $x =1$ will not, and those that do will be complex numbers.....

Comment: The thing though is you don't have to actually *solve* $x^3 = 1$.  You just have to know that there *is* a *complex* solution that satisfies $x^2 + x + 1=0$ and that whatever it is, $x^3 = 1$.

Comment: @fleablood Ah okay thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** As you have correctly observed, we can deduce that $x^3 = 1$.  Now, note that
$$
x^{1999} + x^{2000} = (x^{3})^{666}(x + x^2)
$$

Comment: **Note:** We can only deduce $x^3 = 1\implies x = 1$ if we assume that $x$ is a *real number* (ignoring the possibility of non-zero characteristics). The equation $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ has no real solutions, as you can check by looking at the discriminant.

Comment: so is it that we can't calculate the cube root of a complex or an imaginary number?

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal it is the case that $x^3 = 1$ has three different solutions.  One is $x = 1$.  The other two are
$$
x = -\frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i
$$
these other two cube roots of $1$ are the complex solutions to $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$.

Comment: Oh so it is always safe to take powers of a given equation but the roots should be taken with care as this can create additional solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @AradhyeAgarwal that isn't exactly correct, but it's close enough that I'm afraid to create more confusion by correcting it.

Answer (score 5):

$x^{1998}(x^2+x)=-x^{1998}=-(x^{3})^{666}=-1$

Answer (score 0):

There is nice relation here 
$$x^{2000}+x^{1999}=-x^{1998}=x^{1999}+x^{1997}$$
which is why
$x^3=1$
So
$$x^{1998}(x+x^2)=({x^{3}})^{666}(-1)=-1$$